# numpy の array 変数(例えば、x_data)を x_data.shape[0] と書くと赤線が表示されるが、正常に動作する

Tags: vscode

VSCode上で `x_data.shape[0]` の様にコードを書くと赤線が表示され "unsubscriptable" となるが、正常に実行される。

コードを `x_data.shape` と書いた場合、赤線は表示されない。
VSCode 以外のエディタで同様なコードを書いても、警告等は出ない。
VSCodeのバグ？

Comment: Issue として挙がっていましたが、pylint の問題だという事で closed になっていますね。[Value 'M.shape' is unsubscriptable · Issue #8300 · microsoft/vscode-python](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/8300)

Comment: 情報、ありがとうございます。「The code still runs well, but the red is a bit annoying.」同様の現象ですね。どうしょうかな？